# $M<K\rtimes H$ is a semidirect product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product, group-extensions

Let $H,K$ be two finite groups, $K$ abelian, and let $M$ be a subgroup of $K\rtimes H$.

Consider the projection $\pi:K\rtimes H \rightarrow H$ on the Second factor.

Let us suppose that $\pi(M)=H$. Is true in this case that 
$M$ is isomorphic to $K'\rtimes H$ for a suitable $K' <K$?

My claim is that it is true and that it is possible to construct an injective group omomorphism

$j:Ker \pi_{|M} \rtimes H \rightarrow M$ and then conclude using some classical arguments about group extensions.

Any help (or remark about the incompleteness of the question) is well accepted.
Thank you.

Comment: The natural choice of $K'$ is the kernel of $\pi$, which seems to work.

Comment: I agree with you: I tried to build a map from the sidirect product between $H$ and $Ker \pi$ but it seems not so easy to prove it is an iso.

Comment: I think I spoke to soon, and could be false although maybe the assumption that $K$ is abelian changes things.

Comment: No, there are many counterexamples, because there is no reason for $M$ to even contain $H$. Take $K\rtimes H$ to be $S_3$ for example.

Comment: @verret You are completely right and I correct my request. However, I do not understand why close the question...

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question

Comment: @SabinoDiTrani  I voted to close because there was no context to the question, what you had tried, why you might think it's true, etc. Moreover, the smallest nontrivial semidirect product was already a counterexample, which led me to believe you hadn't put much thought into the question.

Comment: Anyway, the answer is still no, and now the second smallest nontrivial semidirect product is a counterexample. Let $G$ be the dihedral group of order $8$, let $K$ be a Klein group inside $G$ and let $H$ be generated by an involution not in $K$. Then $G=K\rtimes H$. Now, let $M$ be the unique cyclic subgroup of order $4$ in $G$. We have $\pi(M)=H$, but $M$ cannot be expressed as a non-trivial semidirect product.

Comment: Thank you! You're right: it was very simple.  I had in my mind some more complicated stuff...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are many counter-examples.

For example, $K\rtimes H$ could be the dihedral group of order $8$, with $K$ a Klein group, $H$ generated by an involution outside of $K$ and $M$ cyclic of order $4$. We have $\pi(M)=H$ but $M$ cannot be expressed as a non-trivial semidirect product.

You can also take $K\rtimes H=C_4\times C_2$, with $K$ cyclic of order $4$, $H$ cyclic of order $2$ and $M$ a different cyclic subgroup of order $4$.